# How to create multiple arrays by grouping together key-values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, key

I have a list of objects

```js
storage = [{
  "name": "PAYR AS",
  "year": "2016",
  "importance": 0.015
}, {
  "name": "ENTRILLO AS",
  "year": "2017",
  "importance": 0.43200000000000005
}, {
  "name": "ENTRILLO AS",
  "year": "2017",
  "importance": 0.43200000000000005
}]
```

and by this array I wish to create a new array with two lists inside a list, where we have sorted by the name key, as such

```js
list = [
  [{
    "name": "PAYR AS",
    "year": "2016",
    "importance": 0.015
  }],
  [{
    "name": "ENTRILLO AS",
    "year": "2017",
    "importance": 0.43200000000000005
  }, {
    "name": "ENTRILLO AS",
    "year": "2017",
    "importance": 0.43200000000000005
  }]
]
```

Is there any easy way to do this in javascript?

I've tried creating a set amount of new arrays and appending into them, however, then I've run into the problem that I need to know how many name-elements I have beforehand, which I do not necessarily know.

Thanks, and sorry if this is a stupid question!

Comment: `var list = storage.map(i => [i]);`

Comment: Looks more like you want to group them by year

Comment: I'll do that, thanks mplunjan. And to you other comment, yes, in this case I could have sorted by year, but generally the years in my case don't always coincide with how I want to group them.

Answer (score 0):

Start by making a map that maps the grouping key to the items (this would in my opinion also be easier working with). In your example it's `name`. You can use thise map to created a nested array:

```js
const rawData = [
  {
    "name":"PAYR AS",
    "year":"2016",
    "importance":0.015,
  },
  {
    "name":"ENTRILLO AS",
    "year":"2017",
    "importance":0.43200000000000005,
  },
  {
    "name":"ENTRILLO AS",
    "year":"2017",
    "importance":0.43200000000000005,
  },
];

const companyToData = rawData.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const foo = acc[item.name] ? acc[item.name] : [];
  return {
    ...acc,
    [item.name]: [
      ...foo,
      item,
    ],
  };
}, {});

const data = Object.values(companyToData);
console.log(data);
```